# Linux device driver stops write after 8192 Bytes

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I need to write a Linux Kernel Module that is supposed to be very simple and easy to understand that transfers data from user into kernel space. I try to achieve this by creating a character device, that can be written to. When a certain termination character is received, a parsing function is called that handles the input. The read operation for that character device just resets the state.

Now the problem is that after 8192 or 2^13 Bytes, the character device automatically stops the write procedure, so the module only works as long as the string that is fed into it is <= 8192 Bytes.

So far I've not found any mention of this cap in any source, therefore it is unclear how to proceed in this case. The emphasis of this project is not performance. Users with a basic understanding of C, Operating Systems, Virtual Memory,... should be able to understand the resulting source code.

Now my question is: Is there a way I can avoid this limitation when passing data from user into kernel space via a character device?

Comment: You should include code from your device driver so we can see what may be the issue.

Comment: If you are designing your driver to work with `read` and `write` then you should NOT expect the entire data to be fed to (or read from) the driver with a single `read` or `write`. You should not try forcing that, as it is clearly stated in the syscall documentation for read and write that those functions can very well process less than the requested amount. The programmer needs to take that into account, there's nothing you can do about it from the driver side.

Comment: The `write` system call is not intrisically limited to 8192 bytes. Either your "write" file operation handler function is limiting it or the user space application is simply not trying to write more than 8192 bytes at a time.

Comment: @IanAbbott You were right! I don't know why, but using cat txt > /dev/my_char_dev was the problem. Did a short Python wrapper and it worked instantly. I would mark your comment as the solution to the problem, but I am not sure how. Do you maybe know?

Comment: @achnichtsowichtig You can't mark the comment as a solution on SO, it has to be an actual answer. As for default block size that `cat` uses for `write()` syscall: I guess `dd` tool can be used with specified `bs=` param, no need to implement Python wrapper for that. The reason why `cat` might limit block size is probably due to performance reasons, maybe it's trying to adhere to FS block size, etc. Maybe you can find more insights [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245499/how-does-cat-know-the-optimum-block-size-to-use).